# Why is this line appearing across my procedural material?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I have tried to texture an orange with the shader editor after uwrapping the object, and I got this strange trace on the mesh:

[image]

I want to make it disappear but I didn't find any issue. I have tried merge by distance but it doesn't work.

This is the link of the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps flip normals? Could you please share your file?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have already tried flip normals but it doesn't change anything,how to share the file?

Comment: copy the address of this page, click on the link and paste the address in the field where it asked, upload your file

Comment: What version of Blender are you using, @AntaliaAriel? I opened your file in Blender 2.80, but the line in your picture is not present for me.

Comment: He is using Ver. 2.80.75... Maybe it is a graphic card issue (bad driver, or something ?)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, its not necessary to do UV unwrap for procedural textures. Try setting the texture coordinate node to OBJECT and see if it still shows that trace.

Edit : I downloaded your Blend file, but there is no line appearing in the viewport.[image]

Not even in the render (Cycles) :
[image]

(The light is a bit weird btw)

Comment: I think we should **always UV unwrap** for procedural textures. The UV map is additional information beside the vertices data. Those primitive object we added include a default UV map for conveniences. Once you change those vertices, the UV need to be rearrange for sure.